# Заданное приведение является недопустимым, задание значения двухмерному массиву

Tags: c#, winforms

Я пытаюсь скопировать значения таблицы в двухмерный массив:

```
int[,] arr = new int[,] { { }, { } };
for (int i = 0; i < numericUpDown1.Value; i++)
{
    for(int j = 0; j < numericUpDown2.Value; j++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(i + " " + j);
        arr[i, j] = (int)dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value;
    }
}
```

Вот как выглядит интерфейс:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но показывает ошибку `Заданное приведение является недопустимым`.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что делать?

Comment: чтобы привести ячейку к инту, нужно чтобы в ячейке был инт, а там что-то, чего вы не показываете как туда записали. Или вы в интерфейсе вводили?

Comment: Я добавил то как выглядит интерфейс, проблема в том, что программа воспринимает всё написанное в клетке за тип object, поэтому я привожу к int.

Comment: Сейчас у Вас ошибка во время вычисления правой части операции присваивания. Следующей будет ошибка во время вычисления левой части.

Comment: `Convert.ToInt32(...)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В ячейке в данном конкретном случае `string`, а не `int`.

```
int rows = dataGridView1.RowCount;
int cols = dataGridView1.ColumnCount;
int[,] arr = new int[rows, cols];
for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(i + " " + j);
        if (int.TryParse(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value.ToString(), out int value)
        {
            arr[i, j] = value;
        }
    }
}
```